# Trying to prepopulate my android phonegap app with an sqlite db

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

Been trying to populate my phonegap app with an sqlite database. I have confirmed the database with the SQLite Browser for windows. Have placed this in the assets folder. I have seen several plugins that claim to offer this functionality as standard, and they all haven't worked.

I am using the sqlitePlugin. How do i get this working simply.

Thanks

https://github.com/cugwuh182/New_School

Answer (score 1):

Can you give a try to this. http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

If that don't work for you, check step - 4 & 5 over here http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap

Please share your view if it don't work. :)

Comment: I gave the first option a try and wasnt able to get it to work. I guess it tries to copy but fails and creates a new (empty) database.

Also tried the second link (steps 4 & 5) and i couldnt find the line in the sqlitePlugin.java file.

I'm really stuck right now. Here is the link to my github
https://github.com/cugwuh182/New_School